# Click and download all items on list Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script which downloads all Japanese Machine Monthly Tool order PDFs

First step was trying to loop through each year (2010-2019) and print all the list items. Which I have achieved.

The second part is to click each list item (which will download each pdf). This is where I am looking for help.

```
enter code here
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python\chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get("http://www.jmtba.or.jp/english/date/2019/?cat=169")
time.sleep(3)


list1 = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']

i=2010
while i<=2019:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(i)).click()
    # Print all Monthly Machine Tool Orders
    langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#left > ul.news_archive")
    for lang in langs:
        print(lang.text)
        lang.click()
    i = i + 1
```

Prints all the titles of every PDF but does not click and download them. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `time.sleep(3)` funstion, always use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python\chromedriver",options = chrome_options)
driver.get("http://www.jmtba.or.jp/english/date/2019/?cat=169")

i=2010

while i<=2019:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(i)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "news_archive")))
    results = driver.find_element_by_class_name("news_archive")

    rows = results.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

    for row in rows:
        #  get pdf link
        a = row.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        # download pdf
        a.click()

    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching ul part so u can't click them.

```
Go to website > Right click > analyze > Drag your mouse on links
```

You will see your links in span so you need to search span parts.

```
langs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'text']//a")

langs.click()
```

When you change your code like above it will solve your problem.Please say me if it works

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [`sleep()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm) is a some form of an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), consider switching to [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead.

   - remove `time.sleep(3)`
   - replace this line:

     ```
     driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(i)).click()
     ```

     with this one:

     ```
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, str(i)))).click()
     ```

   check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more details
2. Your CSS selector is not very correct, it should target [`a` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

   ```
   langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#left > ul.news_archive > li > span.text > a")
   ```
3. Downloading files using browser is extremely inefficient, I would suggest using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) instead like:

   ```
   urllib.request.urlretrieve(lang.get_attribute('href'), lang.text + '.pdf')
   ```